# Expanding a Kafka consumer pool whilst ensuring all messages are processed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to use Kafka in a traditional message queue configuration. That is:

1. producers can start writing to the topic before consumers start
2. a given topic with a number of consumers
3. consumers can be added to increase throughput
4. whatever the configuration, all messages are eventually processed

A: Point 1 means that I think I need to start my initial consumers off with `auto.offset.reset = earliest` or I will miss messages that were sent before the consumers started.

Point 3 means that I can rebalance by adding consumers. Assuming that point A is correct, which value should I use for `auto.offset.reset`?

B: If I set `auto.offset.reset = earliest` then will I process duplicate messages? (I understand that the act of rebalancing itself may result in duplicate message processing).

C: Or should I set `auto.offset.reset = latest`? If so, will Kafka ensure that all messages are processed?

D: Does this mean that I need a different configuration value of `auto.offset.reset` for consumers that start at different times?

I'm using current version 0.10.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic principle in setting up a consumer in Kafka, `Consumer` and `Consumer Group`. But the concept of `auto.offset.reset` remains unchanged.

> A: Point 1 means that I think I need to start my initial consumers off with auto.offset.reset = earliest or I will miss messages that were sent before the consumers started.
>
> Point 3 means that I can rebalance by adding consumers. Assuming that point A is correct, which value should I use for auto.offset.reset?

I presume you are adding new consumers to the same group. In this case, you have to enhance partitioning on your topic, or else, new consumers will stay idle. Because, one partition on a topic can only be consumed by one consumer in a consumer group.

If a new consumer needed to consume messages added to the topic before it was started then consumer group setup should be `auto.offset.reset = earliest`. This configuration will only play part when there is no committed offset for that particular partition (in case of re-balancing).

> B: If I set auto.offset.reset = earliest then will I process duplicate messages? (I understand that the act of rebalancing itself may result in duplicate message processing).

No. In case of consumer re-balancing, it fetches the latest committed offset for the assigned partition. It uses `auto.offset.reset = earliest` configuration in the scenario where there are no committed offsets.

> C: Or should I set auto.offset.reset = latest? If so, will Kafka ensure that all messages are processed?

Please read my comment for point B.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I am using a high partition number when I start the topic (100) to allow for expansion. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`auto.offset.reset` is used when there is no initial offset in ZooKeeper or if an offset is out of range. It's only really the first time a consumer group starts that ZooKeeper would lack an offset for it. An out of range offset could occur if all the consumers in a consumer group were down for a period longer than the topic retention period, for instance. So by configuring the retention time appropriately you wouldn't see out of range offsets due to this.

If you used `auto.offset.reset = earliest` then in the circumstances of no initial offset, or out of range offset then it's possible you would reprocess messages. But since you have to cope with the possibility of duplicates *anyway* (since Kafka provides at least once semantics), this shouldn't be any different.

If you used `auto.offset.reset = latest` then in the circumstances of no initial offset, or out of range offset then it's possible you would not process some messages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.